# Consuming a grpc stream fails on de-serializing response

Tags: reactjs, deserialization, grpc, grpc-web

We are trying to use streams with a net core backend but getting deserialize error

```
"grpc":{2 items
    "method":string"*****"
    "error":{2 items
    "code":int2
    "message":string"Error in response deserializer function."
  }
}
```

protoc is version 3.14.0
grpc-web-gen is 1.2.1

command to generate the client is:
protoc -I=./protos ./protos/*.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./dist --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext:./dist

We successfully connect to the endpoint and retrieve the data and the call fails on tying to use response.getMessage()
Since there is no other error message and debugging is not very straightforward any insight on what could cause this error would be welcome :)

thank you

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error with gRPC Web because I copied the example without realizing `getMessage()` was not part of the framework API, but a `message` string field in the example Protobuf definition.

Try using `response` directly (or serializing it with `toObject()`)

```
var stream = echoService.serverStreamingEcho(streamRequest, metadata);
stream.on('data', function(response) {
  console.log(response.toObject());
});
```

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks for sharing it Matteo